# Why does Jinja escape html in a macro?

Tags: html, django, macros, escaping, jinja2

I'm writing a Jinja macro to render some form data in a template, but for some reason the form data renders as escaped text instead of html! Here is my macro, with the first row of the form called:

```
{% macro formrow(field) %}
    <tr>
        <td>form.{{ field }}.label|safe</td>
        <td>form.{{ field }}|safe</td>
        <td>form.{{ field }}.help_text|safe</td>
        <td>form.{{ field }}.errors|safe</td>
    </tr>
{% endmacro %}

{{ formrow('item_name') }}
```

Ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: What is the exact output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are not getting the Jinja template syntax completely yet, regardless, I would recommend doing something like this:

```
{% macro formrow(field) %}
    <tr>
        <td>form.{{ field.label_tag() }}</td>
        <td>form.{{ field.as_widget() }}</td>
        <td>form.{{ field.help_text|safe }}</td>
        <td>form.{{ field.errors.as_ul() }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endmacro %}

{{ formrow('item_name') }}
```